# Returning a reference to a class data member and then trying to change that member

Tags: c++, reference

I've seen other posts on this but didn't really get what happens yet.

so say i have this code:

```
template<typename T>struct S {
    S(T value):val{value}{}
    T& get(){return val;}
private:
    T val;
};
int main(){
S<int>s1{5};
int n = s1.get();
n = 10;
std::cout<<s1.get();
}
```

this prints: 5

my question is why if i returned a reference to val doesn't the value
of val change when i changed the value of n?

Comment: 'cause `n` is no reference, regardless of what it is initialized with.

Comment: Try `int& n = s1.get();` instead.

Comment: oh ok so i need to define a reference variable basically thanks!

Comment: so whats the use of returning a reference from a function?

Comment: @Daniel If you *didn't* return a reference, you couldn't do `int& n = s1.get();`.

Answer (score 5):

When you store the result in `int n` you create a copy. Try:

```
int &n = s1.get();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you do

```
int& n = s1.get();
n = 10;
std::cout << s1.get();
```

You will see 10.